# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline with AWS EB and Dockerrun-aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab

I'm building a gitlab ci/cd pipeline that deploys images from my gitlab container registry to my AWS EB. My current approach is to use docker-compose to pull images and build containers and use Dockerrun-aws.json to authenticate AWS EB to gitlab container registry.
According to AWS EB documentation this should be the format of Dockerrun-aws.json

```
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "3",
 "Authentication": {
 "bucket": "DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
 "key": "mydockercfg"
 }
}
```

My concern is what I should include in mydockercfg file. Currently, I'm using the following Dockerrun-aws.json file,

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "3",
  "Authentication": {
  "bucket": "$AWS_S3_BUCKET",
  "key": "auth.json"
  }
}
```

and auth.json file

```
{
  "auths":{
  "$CI_REGISTRY":{
     "auth":"$DEPLOY_TOKEN"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my gitlab-ci.yml file,

```
deploy:
   image:
     name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
     entrypoint: [""]  

 stage: deploy 

 script:
    - echo "Deployment starts"
    - yum install -y gettext

    - export DEPLOY_TOKEN=$(echo $GITLAB_REGISTRY_TOKEN | tr -d "\n" | base64)
    - envsubst < auth.json > aws-auth.json
    - cat aws-auth.json

    - envsubst < Dockerrun.aws.json > aws-Dockerrun.aws.json
    - cat aws-Dockerrun.aws.json

    - aws s3 cp aws-auth.json s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/auth.json
    - aws s3 cp docker-compose.yml s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/dokcer-compose.yml
    - aws s3 cp aws-Dockerrun.aws.json s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/Dockerrun.aws.json
    - aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name web-app --version-label $CI_PIPELINE_IID --source-bundle S3Bucket=$AWS_S3_BUCKET,S3Key=dokcer-compose.yml
   -  aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name web-app --version-label $CI_PIPELINE_IID --environment-name Web-app-env
```

but when I run this job, AWS EB says forbidden access. How should I change the structure so the EB can pull and deploy images from gitlab container registry